# Like query with alphanum string bindParam

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bindparam

I´m new working with pdo statements and when I try to set a query like this in phpMyadmin sql console, it´s works fine:

```
SELECT name, number FROM client WHERE number LIKE '%30%'
```

Result:

```
|name|number|
|antonio|30857898H|
|andrés|30987454U|
```

But when I pass the params with the method `bindParam()` or the method `bindValue()` or with the type value like `PDO::PARAM_STR` or `PDO::PARAM_INT`, the behaviour is that the query stop in the first number, and don´t get the other characters. The cols are both 'char'...

This is my method:

```
function getQueryData($key,$i_query){

    require_once '../queryList.php';//get all the querys
//$key is an array like this $key[0][0] = ':number', $key[0][1] = '%30%'    
    $this->consulta = $this->conInstance->prepare($gQuery[$i_query]);

    foreach ($key as $clave => $valor) {
        $this->consulta->bindParam($key[$clave][0], $key[$clave][1]);
        }       
    $this->consulta->execute();

    $this->consulta->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $this->consulta;
    //Make the bucle on the system
}
```

Thaks a lot for the help in this comunity, the people here are fantastic

Comment: For the bind version - is your query `WHERE number LIKE :number`?

Comment: Hi everyone, this is the array where i pass all the characters :

 parValue = [
   [':number','%'+i_number+'%'] 

//here other pairs key:value...

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try isolate the param content in the like matching clause as

```
SELECT name, number FROM client WHERE number LIKE concat('%', '30', '%')
```

eg

```
SELECT name, number FROM client WHERE number LIKE concat('%', :your_param , '%')
```

or equivalent

Answer (score 0):

With bind parameters you need pass whole string with '%'

query:

```
SELECT name, number FROM client WHERE number LIKE :your_param
```

code:

```
$value = 'some value';
$this->consulta->bindParam('your_param', '%'.  $value . '%');
```

Comment: In the comment in the code it says the value is `$key[0][1] = '%30%'`

Comment: haven't seen that